# form action and sumbit button onclick function are not working together

Tags: javascript

```
<form name="payform" method="POST">
<input style="display:none" id="txnid" name="txnid" ng-model="transactionid" />
<input style="display:none" id="productinfo" name="productinfo" value="bill payment" />
<input style="display:none" id="mobileNumber" name="phone" ng-model="mobileNumber" />
<input id="buttonPay" type="submit" class="mdl-button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="prePay()" >
</form>
```

my html code looks like this. i have to post the contents of textboxes to pay.jsp file. and i have to perform some additional operations on the submit button's onclick event.

```
 prePay=function(){

...
...
...

document.getElementById("payform").action = "/pay.jsp";
     document.forms["payform"].submit();
  }
```

but when i click submit button the onclick function is not working. just redirecting to the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `getElementById`. Your `form` doesn't have `id`, it has only `name`. Try add `id="payform"` to `form` tag.

Comment: no use. error is gone. but page is not redirecting.

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Can not set property 'action' of null" error because of not defined id. You edited your post and changed the name to id.
That was a question.

Comment: How about change order of two last lines of code? `document.forms["payform"].submit();` before `document.getElementById("payform").action = "/pay.jsp";`?